# Joomla release 3.7.2 appears to have broken the menus

Tags: joomla, menu

I applied the Joomla 3.7.2 update yesterday in my test site. Now when I navigate to CiviCRM the menu doesn't appear at all.

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.19 and Joomla Version is : Joomla! 3.7.2 Stable [ Amani ] 22-May-2017 09:46 GMT.
 The Joomla Platform Version is:    Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT

Anyone else seen this behaviour and , if so, is there a fix for it?

Comment: I also updated Joomla to 3.7.2 yesterday. The CiviCRM 4.7.19 menu still appears and works correctly for me, although I did have incorrect URLs in the links in the Administration Console - fixed by running cleanup caches & update paths.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andrew. My URL wasn't being correctly generated so I added the missing bit (&task=civicrm/admin&reset=1) on myself and then went into Cleanup Cache which appears to have fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if you've checked the civicrm log file. Might help to confirm that it isn't reporting any problems due to permissions. Other than that, might want to take a glance at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location. Its possible you may need to rebuild the menu for some reason. I haven't updated to 3.7.2 yet, so I can't confirm this issue myself.